# how to change the position of HighCharts.js scatterplot marker position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, frontend

Please refer to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/La9s2cp4/)

I want the value of var x1 (i.e, var x1 = 10;) should be change the moment i change the range slider which is::

```
document.getElementById("range").innerHTML
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution for your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/La9s2cp4/5/

```
var chart;

function createChart(){

// Set up the chart
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        margin: 100,
        type: 'scatter',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 10,
            beta: 30,
            depth: 250,
            viewDistance: 5,

            frame: {
                bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
                back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
                side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Draggable box'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click and drag the plot area to rotate in space'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            width: 10,
            height: 10,
            depth: 10
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        title: null
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    zAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        showFirstLabel: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Reading',
        marker: {
            radius: xdata
        },
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [dataG.data1, dataG.data2, dataG.data3]
    }]
});

}
```

Comment: Hi Many Thanks for your resolution, but 1 little glitch..... 3D rotaion stops when you click the range slider